# How to install software from source and tell the apt-get that I have installed the version?

Tags: package-management, apt, compiling, software-sources

For installing software from source:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

How to tell the apt-get that the software has been installed, so that

```
sudo apt-get install someSoftware
```

Will show that the software has been installed?

(the software is in the ubuntu package repository, but with older versaion.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. And in most cases, you shouldn't install a bare source tarball unless there's absolutely no other way. Use a package from Ubuntu, or build a source package from Debian, or anything else. You really want to use Debianized source.

However, you can build/modify a source package:

```
apt-get source some-package
```

Then, after making any changes, build a binary package:

```
cd source-directory
debuild -S
```

Now, you have a .deb package you can install.

**EDIT:** I belatedly remembered `checkinstall`. You can use `checkinstall` to replace the `make install` step. You'll get something that looks very much like your original question asked for, although the last time I worked with `checkinstall` (years ago) it was far from perfect. The other options I mentioned are better than this one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the code in the repository is also old. I have tried to use pinning method for newer package, its dependency crashes my hold system. Building from bare source should not produce such disaster according to the software docs. The dependency for compiling the raw source code is not that strict.

Comment: @HaroldChan: Of course, you're free to compile the raw source. But you can't hook it into package management. Have you checked Debian? There's a good chance that  Debian has a more recent version. Or, if it's been packaged in another format (RPM, etc.), you might be able to use `alien` to convert it to .deb. But having un-managed software in your system can quickly become a nightmare if you aren't careful. I know, because I've experienced it.

Comment: @HaroldChan: I belatedly remembered another option and have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: wow~great~ I will try it later

Comment: It works for me! I used nodejs as the testing app. It works!!