# How can I remove a dependency of a program that clearly doesn't need it?

Tags: apt, package-management, pdf

Ok so I have my main app, Variety, and then a dependency it's installed with it called ImageMagick. The main problem of this dependency it's that it bugs my default pdf reader so everytime I want to open a pdf it'll open ImageMagick instead and it won't let me change defaults for pdf anymore. So next smart step is to uninstall ImageMagick, but if I do that Variety stops working and I really like that app. What can I do?

Comment: *if I do that Variety stops working* which means that, contrary to the assertion in title, it clearly needs it.

Comment: Developers/Packagers create the package rules; if you believe they've made an error you can file a bug, or if a wrong choice in your opinion, you can fork the source code and use another tool to perform the function the developer used the packages/tools they put *depends* rules on & create your own modified package, and use that.   https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/variety

Comment: Variety uses `imagemagick` to provide Wallpaper Filters.  Refer https://github.com/varietywalls/variety/tree/420040281c8b2209987fdeabac6e6b209e884d53 in the "*Runtime Requirements*" section.

Comment: I mean it stops working when I reboot. If I uninstall, then run Variety it runs perfect, even on the GitHub page ImageMagick is labelled as "Optional"

Comment: Optional if you install & compile from source; but it's **not** optional with the pre-packaged version you have installed  (*as stated in my earlier comment if you look*)

Comment: How can I install and compile it?

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/85269/how-to-install-software-from-source-and-tell-the-apt-get-that-i-have-installed-t